# python 3 types module

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why is the `types` module in Python 3 so small?

```
Python 2.7
>>> import types    
>>> print(len([i for i in dir(types) if not i.startswith('__')]))
37


Python 3.2
>>> import types    
>>> print(len([i for i in dir(types) if not i.startswith('__')]))
12
```

Answer (score 16):

In Python 3.x, the `types` module removed all types that are already accessible via easier means like the builtin namespace.  For example, you will see that `ListType` and `IntType` have been removed because you can simply access them via `list` and `int` respectively.

Comment: Is this your suggestion or there is official documentation about this?

Comment: It was discussed in depth on python-dev.  The initial intent was to remove the types module altogether, but it was proven to be impractical because there weren't great places to put some of the remaining types like FunctionType.

Here is evidence of it originally being slated for removal:
http://wiki.python.org/moin/Python3.0

Here is some python-dev discussion:
http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2007-November/075384.html
http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2007-November/075456.html

Comment: +1 Thank you for this info. I couldn't figure out why types.IntType wasn't working in Python 3.7.3. This answers it.